# Why is the variance of 2 dot products sampled from a uniform distribution $1/n$?

Tags: probability, statistics, inner-products, variance

I'm coming from more of a coding background and don't have much of a math background other than linear algebra. I generated multiple plots of distributions of vector dot products with each vector element taken from a uniform distribution between -1 and 1. I noticed the variance follows a trend of $1/n$.

After trying to figure out why that's the case I came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877983/variance-of-dot-product-of-two-normalized-random-vector) giving a general explaianation of why this is the case. However, I wanted to find a more formal proof of why this was the case so I kept looking and found another post giving the full proof [here](https://github.com/BAI-Yeqi/Statistical-Properties-of-Dot-Product/blob/master/proof.pdf).

However, this proof showed that variance is $n$ instead of $1/n$. And in the case of sampling from a uniform distribution, it seems like the variance would become $\inf$. So I'm not sure what's going on here.

[Variance simulations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrc5p.png)

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_vector(dim,elements):
    rand_vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(elements,dim))
    norms = np.transpose(np.tile(np.linalg.norm(rand_vec,axis=1),(dim,1)))
    return rand_vec/norms

elms = 10000
dims = [10,20,50,100,250,500,1000,2000]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(dims),1,figsize=(5,len(dims)*5))
for idx,dim in enumerate(dims):
    vec1 = random_vector(dim,elms)
    vec2 = random_vector(dim,elms)
    dot_prod = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",vec1,vec2)
    dot_mean = np.mean(dot_prod)
    dot_std = np.std(dot_prod)
    
    axs[idx].hist(dot_prod,bins=64)
    axs[idx].set_title("dim="+str(dim)+", mean="+str(round(dot_mean,3))+", std="+str(round(dot_std,3)))
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your simulation?

Comment: @user51547 ok just updated.

Comment: In the proof they don't normalize the vectors before taking the dot product like you do.

Comment: See this post for why the variance is $1/n$ like you suggested: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916/distribution-of-scalar-products-of-two-random-unit-vectors-in-d-dimensions